# string concat in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
delimiter //
create procedure ProductViewAllByName(p_productName longtext)
begin
select  productId as 'Product Code',
        productName as 'Name',
        productGroupId as 'Group ID',
        manufactureId as 'Manufacture ID',
        stockMinimunLevel as 'Stock Minimum Level',
        stockMaximimLevel as 'Stock Maximum Level',
        description as 'Description',
        unitId as 'Unit ID'
        FROM tbl_Product
where productName like p_productName+'%' ;
end //
delimiter ;
```

#### error

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+ '%' ; end' at line 12

Comment: Use `CONCAT()` for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can do it with CONCAT() function

```
where productName like CONCAT(p_productName , '%');
```

Answer (score 1):

replace where condition with:

`where productName like CONCAT(p_productName, '%')`